# Pass variables from python file to robot framework variables

Tags: python, robotframework

I am assigning variables in robot framework as

```
*** Variables ***
${TestNAME}                       test
```

But can I pass variable value from python file?

```
#test.py
var = 'test'
```

Is it possible to assign `var` to `${TESTNAME}`?

Comment: Does this link answer your question? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a file named "test.py" that has variables defined in it, you can import the variables using the robot [variable file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files) feature.

Here's an example, using the pipe-separated format for clarity:

```
*** Settings ***
| Variables | test.py

*** Variables ***
| ${myTestName} | ${var}
```

This works because settings are processed before the `Variables` table. Any variables in the python file can be referenced using the standard robot syntax for variables (eg: python variable `var` is referenced as `${var}`)

Note, however, that `${Testname}` is [automatically set](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables) by robot, so your exact requirement can't be met. If you use a non-automatic variable, you can set it the way you want, which is why the above example used `${myTestName}`.

Answer (score 0):

eg:- The variable file is as shown - var.py

x = 10

y = 20

file1.robot can be written as shown:-

*** Settings ***

Variables  var.py

*** Test Cases ***

KEYW1

```
  Log  ${x}
```